# losing GPS metadata while uploading picture with mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, file-upload, gps, mobile-safari

I have form with a input of type 'file'. The goal is for users to upload pictures from which I extract the GPS data. I have some validation on the server side to check if the metadata is present and if yes, I accept the file.

When I upload a picture from my desktop, everything works fine.

When I upload the same picture via mobile safari (iOS 6.1), my validation fails.

The only explanation I can find is that safari strip the metadata from picture before uploading them but it does not make sense to me so I am open to suggestions

Comment: Safari might strip metadata for privacy reasons or as a result of downscaling the image.

Comment: This is what I am thinking. Going to test it out and return tomorrow with the answer. But I cant figure out why it would do that. And I couldnt find any documentation about it.

Comment: Imagine what happens if someone "anonymously" uploads naked pictures which are GPS-tagged...

Comment: This is not a good reason. GPS tags for pictures are managed in iOS privacy preferences. I dont want my browser to decide what is good for me, especially when the behaviour is different between mobile et desktop...

Comment: When selecting a file, the general expectation is that you upload the bytes of the file. OTOH, when uploading a "photo" on a mobile device, there's no indication what metadata will also be uploaded, so it seems reasonable *not* to upload it. (For example, I might want to geotag photos on holiday but not necessarily upload those tags. I disable geotagging photos entirely to avoid potential issues, but *I shouldn't have to*.)

Comment: I disagree with you TC but I guess I am wrong since after some testing, it seems like the Safari guys think along the same line as you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Safari strip the GPS data of a picture you upload via a file input box BUT it will keep the other EXIF data. And this will happen what ever your privacy setting is.

Comment: FYI since iOS 17 this bug has been fixed https://stackoverflow.com/a/77265722/100731